# How to handle ManyToMany fields while testing django-models?

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, error-handling, django-testing

I am trying to write tests for my django models. However, I've got a problem with testing ManyToManyFields and haven't resolved it yet.

```
class TestVolunteeringModels(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.test_need = sample_need(title="Need", description="Description")
        self.test_opportunity = sample_opportunity(title="Opportunity", description="Description")
        for i in range(10):
            self.test_category = sample_category(name="Category")
            self.test_need.category = self.test_category
            self.test_opportunity.category = self.test_category

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.test_need.delete()
        self.test_opportunity.delete()
```

Which brings me this error:

```
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use category.set() instead.
```

The problem is when I use .set() as written in traceback instructions, like this:

```
self.test_need.category.set(self.test_category)
self.test_opportunity.category.set(self.test_category)
```

It gives me another error, which says "TypeError: 'Category' object is not iterable"

So my question is how can I access ManyToMany field in this case, so I can test it freely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.set()` expects an iterable as argument, but the argument that you pass, `self.test_category`, is not iterable.
You have two options:

- Use `.set([self.test_category,])` instead of `.set(self.test_category)`. Thereby you are passing a list, which is iterable, instead of a single object, which is not iterable (therefor the error message that you get).
- Alternatively, you could use `.add(self.test_category)`. The function `.add()` takes individual objects as positional arguments, and *adds* them to any pre-existing catetories.

You should probably opt for `.set()` though, because this ensures that after its execution, the set of associated categories will be precisely the one that you pass.